# Why does my lens refocus when the f-stop is changed?

Tags: autofocus, aperture, sigma, 50mm, f-stop

I have a prime Sigma f1.4 50mm lens on my Nikon D90 in `P` mode and focus mode on a set point of the field and notice that when I am using a tripod and change the f-stop that the camera changes the autofocus.  Is it just resampling and presumably getting the same focus or does the focus change from one f-stop to the next?

Comment: [Focus shift](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46820/compensating-for-focus-shift) is a common phenomenon in older lenses — not just greater DoF, but actually different focus. I don't know, however, if that's the case with this lens, and/or if the D90 is compensating for it with this, or if something else is going on — so I'm not answering, but I hope answers will address this possibility.

Comment: the problem i have with current answers is that SLRs focus with the aperture at its widest. for this reason, a change in aperture can't have any influence on autofocus.

Comment: I have the same thoughtbas @ths. If it focuses using wide open and then applies a per-apeture correction, it can recompute with the same reading. As for mattdm's point, how come we never worried about it in the pre-auto days, where we manually focused with the apeture wide open?

Comment: Also, what mode are you using? P-mode? Program mode?

Comment: What is the focus mode set to? If it's set to automatically choose appropriate focal points, then maybe its choice is being affected by depth of field. But even then, as @ths says, your lens is wide open when focusing.

Comment: @jdlugosz You _should_ have worried about it, [with some lenses](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46821/which-lenses-show-focus-shift).

Comment: @CharlesLeeRoberts It is P-mode.

Comment: @Myridium It is focusing on a fixed point in the field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does the focus change from one f-stop to the next

Depth of field changes when you change the aperture, so the camera is probably adjusting to ensure that the object at the selected AF point remains in focus. This is particularly important when you increase the aperture (i.e. move to a lower f-number), giving you a narrower depth of field. AF systems aren't perfect, and what the system judged to be acceptably in focus at small aperture may not be acceptable a larger aperture. So yes, the camera is probably "resampling," but it's probably doing so because a small adjustment may be necessary.

Answer (score -1):

If you think about a bigger change in depth of field, like f1.4 to f11, it is a bit more obvious: the autofocus has more 'probably sharp' points to pin down, therefore he needs to recalculate. If you have a smaller change in f-stop, the same happens, but on a much smaller basis and is barely noticeable.

Comment: But since modern cameras focus wide-open, this seems unlikely.

Comment: @mattdm Are you sure about that? Cant recall any of my cameras changing  aperture while focussing.

Comment: They *don't* change while focusing — they stay wide open until right before the shutter is released.

Comment: That is definitely not the case, especially with the camera and lens mentioned. The aperture iris does not change in manual or AP mode.

Comment: ... until you press the shutter, right?

Comment: @mattdm is correct.  F-mount lenses are forced open when first attached to the body and left that way until just before the shutter opens.  It was that way before there was AF, but it's a requirement for AF because there's an aperture limit below which AF will not function.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct of course. How does this work with older lenses without contacts wich are MF only? Newer MF lenses behave the same, is that because of AF peeking?